# Loading initial data at application startup with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use [embedded MongoDB](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) database in a development environment. It is setup empty at the application startup. I would like to load initial data which is needed for the application when the Spring context is setup.

Is there a way in Spring Data MongoDB to point a JSON file(s) which would be loaded into a database (something like import.sql (hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files) in Hibernate or @UsingDataSet in [NoSql Unit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mongeez](https://github.com/secondmarket/mongeez) see wiki link for spring integration [wiki](https://github.com/secondmarket/mongeez/wiki/How-to-use-mongeez)