# Load initial data to Mongo collection using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Is it possible to load initial data, indexing etc into Mongo collection using spring framework.

I have used spring-hibernate to handle the same for mysql using

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/insert.sql</prop>
```

Comment: Try Google for it. Pick an approach & if face a particular issue, ask on SO.

Comment: Did not find anything like I need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051260/loading-initial-data-at-application-startup-with-spring-data-mongodb